# How to get pvalue from statsmodels MANOVA?

Tags: python, statsmodels, manova

How to get MANOVA p-value from this:https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.multivariate.manova.MANOVA.html#statsmodels.multivariate.manova.MANOVA
?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Comment: Bravo, wish more high-ranking users were like you. Actually put in the time to explain why the question is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

```
MANOVA(endog, exog).mv_test().results['x0']['stat'].values[test_id, 4]
```

where `test_id` is different types of MANOVA tests:
Wilks' lambda
Pillai's trace
Hotelling-Lawley trace
Roy's greatest root

Comment: Glad you found an answer. But now imagine just having your question and your answer without further context. Would it mean anything to you? We don't have your data file, so we have no clue, what your input is, what your expected output is, what exactly you are doing with this one-liner. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future reference.